# Translating undercore.js templates using l10n / l20n

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, l20n

I'm using l20n to internationalize a small js webapp. Part of the html is static, where l20n works fine – part of the dom elements are rendered as an underscore template. Is there any way to "trigger" the l20n translation AFTER the dynamic dom elements are created (e.g. as part of the underscore "render" function)?

Using the JS API view.setAttributes(elem, id, args) end up in a "... is not a function" error. Any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your code here? Normally, L20n's mutation observer should pick up any changes to the DOM resulting from the `render` function, as long as you use the `data-l10n-id` and `data-l10n-args` attributes.